# JavaScript equivalent of C#'s Char.IsSymbol

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I'm trying to strip all 'Unicode Symbols' from a string. That is, keeping all multilingual characters but removing *dingbats*, *arrows*, and all of that stuff.

C# has a very handy function called `Char.IsSymbol` that can be run on all characters of a string, stripping the character when the functions returns `true`.

I've been searching on doing something similar in JavaScript. If it's a regex then how can I compile a list of all the unicode ranges of the symbol characters? I looked at [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) but couldn't find something that only filters symbols.

Comment: Following @Luaan's advice, I used XRegExp, but as I didn't want to include the whole library in my main project I 'extracted' the 'native' JS regex object with the `toString()` of the XRegExp object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XRegExp does have support for what you're looking for - http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode

You'd probably match either for `\pL` or `\pS`. You can find a nice list of the typical unicode categories in http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Overall, Unicode is quite tricky. It gives plenty of opportunities for giving you trouble, especially with software that isn't fully Unicode compatible (sadly, this includes JavaScript - see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode for a nice set of example). This is further exacerbated by the fact that JS often runs with double-encoding (HTML+JS, and there's worse cases as well). Somebody will probably find a way to bypass your checks, but I'm afraid there's no easy way to prevent that. Just be on the lookout :)